# Logitech C270 has no video output on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, usb, webcam, logitech

My Logitech C270 webcam no longer works on my desktop, presumably after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.

I've listed some of my system info and logs below. Can anyone provide any advice? Thanks!

## System Info

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Kernel info:

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-88-lowlatency
```

There's exactly one video device:

```
$ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0
```

The webcam is detected:

```
$ lsusb | grep Logitech
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
```

```
$ sudo lshw | grep Logitech -B3 -A6
*-usb:2       
   description: Video
   product: Webcam C270
   vendor: Logitech, Inc.
   physical id: 9
   bus info: usb@3:9
   version: 0.12
   serial: E4E41130
   capabilities: usb-2.00
   configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

The webcam is currently plugged into a USB 2.0 port, since I've seen sources say that it doesn't work with USB 3.0.

## Trying to use the webcam

I tried using `guvcview` and `cheese`; both seem to attempt to use the webcam (on `/dev/video0`), since the green light turns on on the webcam, but there is no video output.

Running `guvcview` shows no video output, and prints the following logs:

```
$ guvcview
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.5
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock

(guvcview:22416): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:19:05.714: GTK+ module libgail.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 22:19:05.714: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Directory not empty
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Directory not empty
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Directory not empty
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Directory not empty
```

`sudo guvcview` also shows no output, with the following logs:

```
$ sudo guvcview 
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.5
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock

(guvcview:10623): IBUS-WARNING **: 22:21:59.845: The owner of /home/username/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

`dmesg` output, featuring me trying out different USB ports at the end:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i -e cam -e video
[    0.054065] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.107416] pci 0000:01:00.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    4.873470] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    4.884978] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[    4.977454] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[    4.977455] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[    4.977455] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
[    4.977456] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[    4.977457] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[    4.977457] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[    4.977511] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9.3/3-9.3:1.0/input/input17
[    4.977579] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.977580] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[  331.230142] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[  331.398836] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
[  331.555247] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[  331.563479] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[  342.858579] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[  342.858593] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[  364.131263] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[  364.131266] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[  473.928780] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[  473.928784] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[  537.498208] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[  537.498212] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[  544.499587] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[  544.499591] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[  563.761048] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[  563.761052] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 1776.868595] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 1776.868598] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 1786.506681] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 1786.506686] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 1830.042444] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 1830.042450] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 1872.183174] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 1872.183178] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 1998.396169] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 1998.396174] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 2004.517466] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 2004.517471] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 2031.841384] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 2031.841389] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 2282.671235] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 2282.671239] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 2324.197277] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 2324.197282] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 2456.664933] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 2456.664938] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 2534.645562] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 2534.645567] uvcvideo 3-9.3:1.0: reset_resume error -5
[ 2871.852239] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[ 2871.942491] uvcvideo 3-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[ 2871.942492] uvcvideo 3-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[ 2871.942493] uvcvideo 3-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
[ 2871.942494] uvcvideo 3-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[ 2871.942495] uvcvideo 3-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[ 2871.942496] uvcvideo 3-12:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ 2871.942562] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-12/3-12:1.0/input/input18
[ 2943.502825] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[ 2943.593046] uvcvideo 3-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[ 2943.593048] uvcvideo 3-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[ 2943.593048] uvcvideo 3-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
[ 2943.593049] uvcvideo 3-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[ 2943.593050] uvcvideo 3-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[ 2943.593050] uvcvideo 3-4:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ 2943.593156] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/input/input19
[ 3022.273264] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[ 3022.363398] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[ 3022.363400] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[ 3022.363401] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
[ 3022.363401] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[ 3022.363402] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[ 3022.363403] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ 3022.363484] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9:1.0/input/input22
[ 3490.979094] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
[ 3491.069227] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
[ 3491.069238] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 6 was not initialized!
[ 3491.069239] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
[ 3491.069240] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
[ 3491.069240] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
[ 3491.069241] uvcvideo 3-9:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[ 3491.069316] input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9:1.0/input/input23
```

Comment: I bought a new webcam, and it still doesn't work despite the indicator light turning on (even on Windows)... scary :(

Comment: I have the same problem with the Logitech QuickCam Pro 9000. Very annoying ; sometimes the framerate is decent, sometimes it's less than 1 FPS.

Comment: Update: my new webcam started working after a while and I have no idea why :) It's an Anivia W8. Meanwhile, the old Logitech hasn't worked a single time since then.